# Can I query a dynamodb table using only a html page?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I am trying to build a simple webpage that there is a input textfield and anyone a fill something in it and press search and when somene press search it takes the input and see if it match in a dynamodb database , so basically I want to build a page that keep my cost extra low where I host it on a awss3 and using only that it connects to dynamodb . Is that possible ? without Lambda. So Clientside code on aws s3 + dynamodb query for ultra low cost hosting. I tried to see on amazon aws but I cant find a working example that why I am asking.

Comment: Maybe try using JavaScript dynamodb sdk in your browser. Assuming it is feasible, you need aws keys and table name to be hardcoded in your webpage. That's kinda vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar but If I create a policy where a user can only query a database (no editing/no deleting ) and use that aws keys is it still kinda vulnerable to attacks ?

Comment: May be less but still vulnerable. Actually, if you feel that querying is not that vulnerable to your application, then as you said attach an IAM policy for db querying and hope it should work

Comment: Was looking for the same and right now a user needs a Facebook account to use your app accessing DynamoDB. So you have to decide yourself if you want to go that way: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html Therefore the risk is reduced by identified customers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  The AWS Javascript SDK is the way to go.

https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

Dynamodb specific:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but my main concern would be security.. In order to perform read/write you need aws secret and key, and it would not be a good idea to add these to your html page as they will be available to everyone to see.

At least you should create a user that can only query your dynamodb table and has no access to anything else in your aws account. Or you can look for a way to authenticate users and authorize them. Maybe through aws incognito.

Comment: Yes I would probably create a user that can only query that database and cant do nothing more on aws and is there any vulnerability with that?

Comment: You should probably be safe then. The risk will be you accidentally add a permission trying to test something and leave it there.

Comment: Also if someone get access to your table name and user secret/key they can run queries that will consume all of your provisioned reads leaving your app dysfunctional.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it **securely**.

You should use [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) to authenticate users instead of embedding your credentials in your source code. [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/) is an example.